# What is the optimal way to write stored procedures/functions that switch between table schemas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 3 tables in the database:

- [Unapproved].[Data]
- [Approved].[Data]
- [History].[Data]

We currently have 3 stored procedures that each run the same select query to get the data from the tables but the only difference is the schema.

What would be an optimal way of doing this say in one stored procedure (preferably without dynamic SQL)

Comment: Just curious, why don't you have just have a [Data] table with an identifier that differentiates the status, so you would have a FK to a status table that would have id's for Unapproved, Approved and History. If an unapproved data got approved you would simply update the StatusID, then you would only need one query and filter by status

Comment: @kd7 Yep, the SIMPLIEST ever state machine splitted to different schemas and tables! Yes, definitely TomTom is right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no optimal way.

You can use an IF .. ELSE IF construct to decide which one to choose.

But they are 3 different objects so this is expected. I'd suggest that you're not using schemas correctly...

From dba.se:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4075/630
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8511/630

Comment: +1. Optimal way is to fire the dude putting up this ridiculous anti pattern schema usage and reconstruct it to be done properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create view like that:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.blabla
AS
SELECT 0 as SourceSchema, otherfields from [Unapproved].[Data]
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as SourceSchema, otherfields from [Approved].[Data]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as SourceSchema, otherfields from [History].[Data]
GO

CREATE PROC GetTheData
@fromwhere int
As
select otherfields from dbo.blabla where SourceSchema = @fromwhere
```

**BUT**

I cannot say that it is an **OPTIMAL** way.

**And** I'm agree with @TomTom under the @gbn post